# Xcode8 download iOS 9.3 Simulator fail

Tags: simulator, xcode8

I downloaded many times, sometimes prompt network problems lead to the failure to download，sometimes prompt "Could not download and install iOS 9.3 Simulator. Failed to mount image: no mountable file systems"。

I try to copy from other computer installed the simulator, the path "~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices" file copy to come over to cover all, still is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have other simulators downloaded on a different machine you can copy them.

1. Go to `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`
2. Right-click the runtime you want and select "Compress <name>.simruntime".
3. Air-drop that ZIP to your other machine.
4. Move the ZIP to `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`.
5. Double-click to unzip. (I suggest closing Xcode and the Simulator while unzipping).

The error you are getting is probably from a corrupted download. There may be a proxy server or a problem with your network connection.

You can close Xcode, clear `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads`, then re-open Xcode. This should make it re-download the index and update its list of downloadable items.

Comment: tks, I solved the problem by replacing the network，I guess your method can solve the problem